# My Android App doesn't list on Google play store on some Samsung Phones?

Tags: android, google-play

I have read through other questions on Published App not showing up in results on certain Phones. But none has helped solve my peculiar case.

My manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="19"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Problem: 
My App doesn't show up in Google Pay Store search results on Samsung Note-2 & Note-3 but shows up on Samsung Note-4 (Strange!!). The App lists in search on other phones like: LG, HTC etc in Google Play Store.

Q. Does the minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version those phone's have but for example if your minsdkversion is 19 then it isn't going to work on phones below api version 19 like the note 2/3.

Comment: SuperThomasLab- Your answer makes sense. I just checked the specifications of Samsung Note-2 and its base OS version is: 4.1.1 Jelly Bean that is equivalent to API level 16 whereas I had set to 19 (supporting 4.4 up on wards only). Let me make change & update the App. Will get back if the change works-Thanks!